Non-atomic probability measures on N
One can intuitively imagine picking a random natural number and ask to what extent the intuition can be axiomatized.
Using the axiom of choice, there is a total finitely additive (monotonic) averaging function $μ$ on sequences of nonnegative real numbers, extending $\lim_{n→∞} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$.  Such $μ$ also yields a finitely additive non-atomic probability measure on $ℕ$.  However, we work with $μ$ here since without countable additivity, the probability measure only suffices to recover $μ$ for sequences of bounded real numbers.
There does not appear to be a single natural choice of $μ$, but the lack of natural $μ$ is not obvious especially if we only need $μ$ for (for example) computable sequences, and any case we can ask which symmetry principles a hypothetical natural $μ$ would satisfy, and then consider their consequences.
Question:  Is there literature on this topic?
Note:  A survey on finitely additive non-atomic probability measures on $ℕ$ would also work even if it does not discuss naturalness.  Among else, I am looking for which symmetry properties $μ$ can or cannot have.  I am also interested in arguments (on either side) on whether natural preferred $μ$ exists for (for example) computable sequences.
Update:  I had hoped that a good survey might answer these and more, but I also have two specific questions.
- Does $μ$ exist that satisfies the basic symmetry principles (especially (2)) below?
- If in addition CH (the Continuum Hypothesis) holds, is there such $μ$ that is also representable as described below in "$μ$ as a limit of measures"?
My notes are below.
Basic symmetry principles
Call a strictly monotonic sequence of natural numbers $n_1,n_2,...\,$ $μ$-equally spaced if there is a function $f:ℕ→ℝ_{>0}$ such that $μ(x_i:i∈ℕ) = μ(\frac{\sum_{j=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} f(j) \, x_j}{\sum_{j=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} f(j)}:k∈ℕ)$ (using 0 in place of $n_0$, but we do not care about finite initial segments).
For typical sequences used in practice, $μ$ is fixed if we assume the following basic symmetry principles (which are based on translation and scale invariance):

For every $k>0$,   $k,2k,3k,...$ is $μ$-equally spaced with constant $f$.
For every $k>0$,   $k,2k,4k,8k,...$ is $μ$-equally spaced with $f(n)=1/n \; (n>0)$.

Notes:
- (2) implies (1).  The choice of the exponentiation base (i.e. 2) is immaterial.
- The summation process of recursively using (2) (what is its name?) corresponds to averaging using one of $1, 1/n, 1/(n \log n), 1/(n \log n \log \log n),...$ as weights.
- To augment (2), we can specify that $μ(x)=∞$ if $\sum \frac{x_n}{n^2}=∞$; with (2), using $n^2$ is equivalent to using $n^{\log n}$ or $n \log^{1+ε} n$.
- One also wants $μ(x)$ to be monotonic in $(\sum_{i=0}^n x_i : n∈ℕ)$.
$μ$ as a limit of measures:  Under CH (or if the dominating number is $ω_1$), I think an appropriate $μ$ can be represented as a limit of a sequence of $ω_1$ unnormalized atomic measures $μ_α$ with $∀x:ℕ→ℝ_{≥0} \, \displaystyle{\lim_{α→ω_1}} μ_α^\inf (x) = \displaystyle{\lim_{α→ω_1}}  μ_α^\sup (x)$ (with $∞=∞$ here) and $∀α ∀β \, (α<β<ω_1) \, ∀x:ℕ→ℝ_{≥0} \, μ_α^\inf (x) ≤ μ_β^\inf (x) ≤ μ(x) ≤ μ_β^\sup (x) ≤ μ_α^\sup (x)$, where $μ_α^\inf (x) = \displaystyle{\liminf_{n→∞}} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i μ_α(i)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} μ_α(i)}$ and analogously with $μ_α^\sup$.
Fractional exponentiation: For appropriate $μ$, we can define the corresponding fractional exponentiation as follows. Let $p = μ([n,r) ∪ [2^n,2^r) ∪ [2^{2^n},2^{2^r}) ∪ ...)$ with $n<r<2^n$ (and using the indicator function for integers in the intervals), and define the $p$th iteration of exponentiation base 2 starting with $n$ to equal $r$.  Thus, finding natural fractional exponential growth rates (see my old questions here and here) is a subquestion of finding natural $μ$.  Unlike exponentiation, tetration base $a>1$ is not analytic except possibly for a single $a$, or rather if a definition of tetration base $a$ is analytic, then using it to define tetration base $b≠a$ gives a non-analytic function. Plausibly, there are no natural fractional exponential growth rates.  However, that does not stop us from listing some desired symmetry principles for $μ$.
Further symmetry principles for $μ$:  To the extent that we have canonical fundamental sequences for ordinals, we can postulate that $f_α$ gives $μ$-equally spaced values, where $f_α$ uses the fast-growing hierarchy of functions.  We can also postulate that the extension (using $μ$) of $f_α$ to non-integral arguments and its inverse are smooth.  Using this, for every $n$,   $n, 2^n, 2^{2^n}, ...$ is $μ$-equally spaced.  We can also postulate that appropriate nonrecursive functions (such as the iterated busy beaver function) give $μ$-equally spaced values.
An attempt at finding $μ$:  One may try to define $μ$ (on a restricted class of sequences) by identifying a sufficiently pseudorandom process that produces unbounded integers.  For example, given a random-enough sample, we can apply $\log_2$ until all values are in $[c,2^c)$, and then use the distribution of those values to define fractional exponentiation.  However, I could not find any such pseudorandom processes.  Even if we use $B^{-1}(B_2(n))$ where $B$ is the busy-beaver function, and $B_2$ is busy-beaver with $0'$ oracle, the resulting values need not be pseudorandom.

possible another tag: reference-request

Thought it does not directly contribute, I'd like to link the following question here so that people stumbling upon one of these questions can find the other.

Here is one reference (not discussing naturalness).  Finitely additive probability measures on N.  Douwen 1992.

Is there literature on this topic?  Try "Banach Limit" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit

@GeraldEdgar I did not know the name.  To clarify, by literature I mean literature helpful for the discussion in the question.  This includes which symmetry properties can Banach limits and especially its generalizations to sequences of unbounded nonnegative real numbers satisfy.  For example, a possible answer might prove that $μ$ with "Basic symmetry properties" (in the question) and under CH representable as described in "$μ$ as a limit of measures" actually exists.

Entire books have been written on Banach limits.  Why not peruse one of them?

The theory of medial limits in Fremlin's Measure Theory (Volume 5, starting at 538P) should help.

Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95954

http://logicandanalysis.org/index.php/jla/article/view/403

I’m not sure if it’s helpful, but the above-linked paper gives you the following.  If you can write down some set of criteria you want your measure to satisfy, and prove that for every epsilon, there is a finite set on which all of your criteria are satisfied within epsilon, then there is a canonical “filter measure” that gives you a finitely additive partial probability measure satisfying the criteria.  If you extend the filter to an ultrafilter, it will yield a total measure.

You may want to look at "Finitely Additive Measures on the Integers" by Dorothy Maharam. Note in particular that finitely additive positive measures on $\mathbb{N}$ are the same as countably additive positive measures on its Stone–Čech compactification $\beta\mathbb{N}$. The 'natural' measures you're after would then be the accumulation points of $N^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N \delta_n$ (of which there are many). On the other hand, all of this stuff relies very strongly on the axiom of choice, so I don't think that there is any of these accumulation points that can actually be described in an unambiguous way.
